# NullPointerException error while loading file

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I'm trying to load a background picture for this game, the file is in the same folder as the class file and there is only one folder for it all. I've searched for different ways to reference the file and all have failed. This is the error thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ThrustR.<init>(ThrustR.java:28)
    at ThrustR.main(ThrustR.java:35)
```

And here is the code:

```
public class ThrustR extends JFrame
{
    public String path;
    public File file;
    public BufferedImage image;

    public void setValues() throws IOException
    {
        path = "CityRed.jpg";
        file = new File(path);
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    }

    public ThrustR(String title)
    {
        super(title);

        JLabel back = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Main Window
        ThrustR frame = new ThrustR("ThrustR");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(720,480);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }   
}
```

Comment: path = "CityRed.jpg"; doesn't returns valid path in HDD, Java package, nor BufferedImage, then reason for NullPointerException,  for more info to read Oracle tutorial about Java packages

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
getClass().getResource("/CityRed.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your `setValues()` method from anywhere.

What I can make out is, when the execution of program starts it goes to the `main()` method where you are creating object of your class `ThrustR frame = new ThrustR("ThrustR");` and it will call it's constructor, which is

```
public ThrustR(String title){
    super(title);
    JLabel back = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
}
```

And in this you are creating another object of ImageIcon i.e. `new ImageIcon(image)` and at this moment `image` will be null. As `setValues()` has not got called so far and by default `public BufferedImage image;` will be null.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't make a call to setvalues() method. I have done some changes in your code and its working for me you can try .

```html
public class ThrustR extends JFrame {
//  public String path;
//    public File file;
//    public BufferedImage image;

//    public void setValues() 
//    {
    // path = "/CityRed.jpg";
    // file = new File(path);
    //image = ImageIO.read(file);
//    }
    public ThrustR(String title) throws IOException {
        super(title);
        String path = "CityRed.jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        JLabel back = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        this.add(back);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Main Window
        ThrustR frame = new ThrustR("ThrustR");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(720, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```